# replacing letter(s) in words for hangman error

Tags: java, string, object, char

```
 public class Hangman {

    private String secret;
    private String disguise;
    private int guessCount;
    private int wrong;

    public Hangman() {
        secret="word";
        disguise="????";
        guessCount=0;
        wrong=0;
    }

    public void makeGuess(char input) {
        String temp;
        temp=disguise;
        for (int i=0; i<secret.length(); i++) {
            if (secret.charAt(i)==input) {
                disguise=disguise.replace(disguise.charAt(i), input);
            }
        }
        if (temp.equals(disguise))
            wrong++;
    }
```

I'm having some difficulty with my code, specifically the disguise=disguise.replace line. The objective of my code is to replace the symbol in disguise with the letter in secret via guessing from the user. The for loop goes through all of the letters in the secret word and looks for matches between the user inputted character and the letters in the secret word. 
If there is a match, I want the program to replace the symbol in disguise at that position with the character from input.

Instead what's happening is my code is replacing all the letters in disguise with the letter that the user guesses if it's in the word secret.

```
Example:
????
w
wwww (disguise)
word (secret)

what I want:
????
w
w???
word
```

This is my demo class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HangmanDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char input;
        Hangman game = new Hangman();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(game.getDisguisedWord());
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            String line=keyboard.nextLine();
            input = line.charAt(0);

            game.makeGuess(input);
            game.guessCount();
            game.getDisguisedWord();
            game.isFound();
            System.out.println(game.getDisguisedWord());
            System.out.println(game.getSecretWord());
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone could point out what is wrong with my replace statement in the class coding, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some sample input & output.

Comment: Something else you might want to consider is what happens if they guess a letter that they have already entered? Currently all solutions below will do nothing, as letter has already be replaced but you might want it to be a wrong guess or display that they have already guess that

Answer (score 4):

Since your "disguise" contains only `?` and `replace(char oldchar, char newChar)` actually replaces all occurrences of `oldchar`, your whole string is being replaced.

What you really want is to replace a character at a specific position, and for that you could use `StringBuilder#setCharAt`. See my example below:

```
public void makeGuess(char input) {
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(disguise);
    boolean wrongGuess = true;
    for (int i=0; i<secret.length(); i++) {
        if (secret.charAt(i) == input) {
            temp.setCharAt(i, input);
            wrongGuess = false;
        }
    }

    disguise = temp.toString();
    System.out.println(disguise);
    if (wrongGuess){
        wrong++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your disquise word is all ???? so no matter what you input, the code `disguise.charAt(i)` will always be a `?` so on every ? will be replaced

What you want is `secret.charAt(i)` like below

```
public void makeGuess(char input) {
    String temp;
    temp=disguise;
    char[] disquiseChars = disquise.toCharArray();  //added
    for (int i=0; i<secret.length(); i++) {
        if (secret.charAt(i)==input) {
           //disguise=disguise.replace(secret.charAt(i), input); 
           //Change in above line, but this still wont work, try this now
           disquiseChars[i] = input;
        }
    }
    disquise = disquiseChars;
    if (temp.equals(disguise))
        wrong++;
}
```

Not the most elegant solution but should do the trick

**Edit:** Below would be a quick way to check if they have already guess a letter, but only guessed a correct letter I realise now

```
public void makeGuess(char input) {
    if(diquise.contains(String.valueOf(input))
    {
        System.out.println("You have already guessed " + input);
        wrongGuess++; // if you decide
        return;
    }
    String temp;
    temp=disguise;
    char[] disquiseChars = disquise.toCharArray();
    for (int i=0; i<secret.length(); i++) {
        if (secret.charAt(i)==input) 
        {
           disquiseChars[i] = input;
        }
    }
    disquise = disquiseChars;
    if (temp.equals(disguise))
        wrong++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the Replace function in the loop with a `disguise[i] = input;` and as the loop continues, all the changes are made as needed :)

The issue here is as Java Devil suggested, you're replacing all the '?' with the input!

**Edit :** Sorry I was thinking .NET when I said `disguise[i]`.

Either declare Disguise as a `StringBuilder` as use `disguise.setCharAt(i, input);` or Do 
`disguise = disguise.substring(0,i) + input + disguise.substring(i+1, disguise.length());`

The 2nd version works for strings too. You are creating 2 substrings first from 0 to the index of the position you want to change and then adding the new character & concatenating the 2nd substring from i+1 to the end

Hope it helps..

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [String.replace(char,char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) docs and you will see that it replaces EVERY instance of the oldChar with the newChar.  This means that every '?' will be replaced by 'w'.  What you want to do instead is replace only the character at that given position.

To do this, you can use a char[] instead of a string and easily replace characters by index.  To get a char[] from a String, simply call the [String.toCharArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) method on the secret word.

```
public class Hangman {

    private String secret;
    private char[] disguise;
    private int guessCount;
    private int wrong;

    public Hangman() {
        secret="word";
        disguise="????".toCharArray(); // <-- Basically this changes
        guessCount=0;
        wrong=0;
    }

    public void makeGuess(char input) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i=0; i<secret.length(); i++) {
            if (secret.charAt(i)==input) {
                disguise[i] = input; // <-- Basically this changes
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
            wrong++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

String chartAt(i) return character not index. If you replace the character than all character occurance will be replaced.

If you go through the Java Documentation then you have to learn why replace(char, char) method does not replace single character. Following qoute is from Java Docs.

> public String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)
>
> Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of
>   oldChar in this string with newChar. If the character oldChar does not
>   occur in the character sequence represented by this String object,
>   then a reference to this String object is returned. Otherwise, a new
>   String object is created that represents a character sequence
>   identical to the character sequence represented by this String object,
>   except that every occurrence of oldChar is replaced by an occurrence
>   of newChar.